# Catboost: what are reasonable values for l2_leaf_reg?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, catboost

Running catboost on a large-ish dataset (~1M rows, 500 columns), I get:
Training has stopped (degenerate solution on iteration 0, probably too small l2-regularization, try to increase it).

How do I guess what the l2 regularization value should be? Is it related to the mean values of y, number of variables, tree depth?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have more chances of getting an answer for this in [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you will find an exact answer to your question because each data set is different.

However, based on my experience values from a range between 2 and 30, is a good starting point.